# Pourquoi les animaux ont-ils des noms différents dans l'assiette ?

Tags: usage, noms, zoologie

Je pense notamment à *cochon* et *porc* et *cabillaud* et *morue*. En général on ne mange pas du cochon, mais du porc, et on ne pêche pas de la morue mais du cabillaud.

Y a-t-il d'autres animaux, ou d'autres aliments, sujets à ce genre de changement de nom ? Ces étrangetés sont-elles causées par des phénomènes comparables ou chaque cas est-il indépendant ?

Comment: Parce que c'est plus facile pour le faire manger aux enfants (et aux dames sensibles) : « oh, le beau cochon — tu viens, on va manger du rôti de porc ? ». La preuve : le lapin porte le même nom dans sa cage et dans l'assiette, et c'est très dur de faire manger du lapinou aux enfants (et à quelques adultes)…

Comment: @F'x: Ha, touché :) Je pense que pour le lapin c'est beaucoup un problème d'yeux.

Comment: Evpok a dit : « En général on ne mange pas du cochon, mais du porc ».
Je cite un extrait de l'article **cochon** du  *Dictionnaire Culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey) :
« On emploie porc pour la viande fraîche, porc et cochon pour la charcuterie. »
En ce qui me concerne quand je mange du boudin, je mange du cochon (et pas du porc) mais je me demande si c'est mon origine méridionale qui est en cause ?

Comment: Tempérons... Les exemples donnés ne sont que des exceptions. On mange du boeuf, de la vache, du veau, de l'agneau (c'est tout mignon un agneau !), même du cochon de lait (c'est pas tout mignon un petit cochon ?), etc. Il n'y a que pour certains animaux que cette distinction existe, et encore n'est pas très stricte en français.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que la différence soit si marquée. En anglais, la distinction est beaucoup plus fréquente: les animaux ont une origine anglo-saxone, alors que les plats ont souvent une orgine française.

Comment: @subtenante On ne mange pas de vache, On mange du boeuf! Par contre, la peau devient du cuir de vache (ou *vachette* mais pas du boeuf). Les bovidés changent de sexe à la mort (puis font le tour du monde, mais c'est une autre histoire...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La double appellation me semble assez clairement dictée par une volonté plus ou moins consciente de détacher l'animal qui est au bout de sa fourchette de celui qu'on aime à voir gambader dans les prés.

Même si je ne suis pas sûr que les noms d'animaux français soient le meilleur exemple (comme le fait remarquer [mouviciel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/pourquoi-les-animaux-ont-ils-des-noms-differents-dans-lassiette/1212#1212), ce n'est pas si courant), on peut noter que:

1. L'usage d'euphémismes est *très* fréquent dès qu'il s'agit de parties du corps, et encore plus pour les abats: on mange des *ris de veau* (pas du thymus), du *mou* (pas du poumon), du *rognon* (pas du rein), etc.
2. Les euphémismes alimentaires (noms d'animaux et parties du corps) existent probablement dans toutes les langues (je pourrais en citer en anglais, français, espagnol, allemand ou japonais… et je doute que ce soit les seules langues où il y en ait).

Comment: Et pourquoi ce serait volontaire? Qu'est ce qui existe d'abord: l'appellation populaire ou l'appellation scientifique? Pourquoi la cuisine ne garderait pas naturellement l'appellation populaire?

Comment: @Nikko: je ne pense vraiment pas que "mou" ait jamais été utilisé pour parler d'un poumon, autre que dans une assiette (etc.). Comme je le disais, je pense que la volonté en question est plus ou moins consciente: quelle que soit l'origine des termes euphémistiques, le consensus se sera petit à petit placé de leur coté, par préférence...

Answer (score 11):

La situation n'est pas comme en anglais où *pork* est utilisé exclusivement pour la viande et *swine* pour l'animal.

*Porc* et *cochon* désignent à la fois l'animal et la viande.  *Porc* est d'un niveau de langage légèrement plus soutenu et ce doit être la raison pour laquelle les bouchers (et les éleveurs de porcs) préfèrent l'employer.

*Morue* et *cabillaud* désignent le même poisson (ou plutôt peuvent désigner : les noms de poissons sont extrêmement mal fixés et d'un bassin à l'autre, le même terme va désigner des poissons différents) et à nouveau les deux termes désignent aussi la chair même s'il y a une préférence pour un terme ou l'autre suivant la préparation. La préférence actuelle pour *cabillaud* pour le poisson frais a peut-être commencé à l'époque où le poisson frais est devenu disponible pour éviter l'association trop immédiate avec la version salée qui était vendue sous l'autre nom (sans oublier avec l'huile de foie de morue et les usages péjoratifs du nom).

Comment: On dirait plus souvent *pig* que *swine*, mais effectivement, on ne mange pas de *pig* :) Il me semble me rappeler une pub pour du Justin Bridou (ou autre) avec des petits cochons en dessin animé. J'avais alors remarqué à un ami que jamais pareil pub aurait vu le jour en Angleterre !

Answer (score 5):

On élève des porcs, donc c'est le même nom que ce qu'on mange.

On mange du cabillaud. La morue n'est qu'une préparation particulière du cabillaud.

Il me semble que la différence de noms est plus marquée en anglais.

Answer (score 3):

Question de *point de vue*.

C'est un éleveur, un enfant ou un observateur qui parle des animaux vivants.

C'est un cuisinier qui présente des plats à ses convives.

L'éleveur parlera du *poumon* de son animal, s'il doit en faire mention.

Le chasseur parlera également des parties du corps par leur nom *fonctionnel*.

Le cuisinier, manipulant de la *viande* (et non de la chair ou des muscles), va chercher à classifier ses morceaux en fonction de leur consistance et de la manière de les apprêter. Puis leur trouvera des noms *appétissants*.

La volonté de détacher le contenu de l'assiette de l'animal familier est probablement à mi-chemin entre *l'effet de bord* et la volonté mielleuse de *ne pas reconnaitre celui que l'on mange*. Je pense d'ailleurs que cette gêne est très *localisée* dans le temps et dans notre culture. (Manger l'autre est une manière de partager l'être et/ou de s'approprier ses forces…)

Je crois simplement que les choix de noms donnés aux animaux ne sont pas le fait des mêmes personnes que celui des noms donnés aux plats.

Une *sardine à l'huile d'olive* devient dans un *grand* restaurant un *prince des mers dans son jus des fruits du midi*.

Answer (score 1):

Le mot bœuf vient du latin. C'est le même mot qu'en anglais (beef) et d'autres langues européennes. En français on utilise aussi bovin ou bovine (clairement du latin [bos](http://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bos)).

Le sens du mot a changé avec le temps, mais le sens premier reste: un taureau castré. Donc un animal qui lui aussi vit dans les prés. (Je peux voir 1 taureau, 5 bœufs et 6 vaches dans ce champs).

Le mot porc vient du latin [porcus](http://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porcus). À nouveau, c'est le même mot en anglais (pork) ainsi que d'autres langues. Comme le disent les autres ici, c'est le *mot officiel*.

Le mot cochon n'a pas une origine claire; sauf que le mot vient de 'une coche'. L'étymologie supposée serait [le nom donné aux appelés](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cochon#.C3.89tymologie) (militaires qui ne sont pas soldats de carrière). Ceci me fait vraiment penser que le mot a vraiment été transformé pour signifier "sale" (comme dans "quel cochon!"). Les porcs étant sales, le mot a dû être transmis de l'homme à l'animal. Donc ça me semble très logique que l'on mange du porc! De plus le mot cochon ne se retrouve pas en Anglais ou d'autres langues.

Ceci dit, comme certaines personnes l'on souligné, on mange du cochon de lait.

Bon... pour le poisson, je n'y connais rien. Mais je suis sur que l'on peut trouver une explication similaire.

Comment: Si mes souvenirs sont bons, quand on mange du bœuf, ça peut très bien être de la vache.

Comment: Oui, tout à fait. Mais contrairement aux autres je ne crois pas que le mot utilisé en cuisine a quelque chose à voir avec le fait que les enfants vont manger du "bœuf" mais pas de la "vache".

Answer (score 1):

En réalité en cuisine on ne cuisine pas la vache dans la tradition car elle fournit du lait. Comme on cuisinait plus le coq (coq au vin). Si on regarde une carte assez vieille on y trouvera des faisans, des pigeons dans la plupart des menus. C'est très récent l'éthique liée à la viande et les premiers végétariens le faisaient surtout par manque de moyens ou pour des raisons diététiques. Les noms des producteurs et celui consommateurs étaient différents du fait des régions déjà, pour exemple le bar et le loup de mer. Dans 100 ans des internautes auront peut être la même discussion avec les pains au chocolat et chocolatines en disant que c'est pour ne pas avoir la consommation de beurre sur la conscience.^^

Answer (score 1):

En fait ça dépend de plusieurs choses: le statut (l'animal peut changer de nom si il est vivant ou mort); le type de préparation (je pense à l'églefin qui devient haddock); ou encore des appellations commerciales (la roussette qui devient la saumonette).

Pour les viandes carnées, je ne m'y connais pas assez, mais pour les poissons j'ai trouvé un article sympathique sur les [poissons qui changent de nom](https://jeretiens.net/ces-poissons-qui-changent-de-nom/) dans lequel les raisons des changements de noms sont très bien expliquées.